# Float32Array set property not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I've added 3 properties called 'x', 'y' and 'z' to Float32Array.
The getter works fine in both, chrome and firefox, but it seems like the setter only works in chrome. Why is that? Is it a bug? Is there a way to get it working in firefox?

```
Object.defineProperty(Float32Array.prototype, 'x', {
    get: function(){
        return this[0];
    },
    set: function(x){
        this[0] = x;
    }
});


// creating a Float32Array-Vector using mjs.js  
var vector = V3.$(1,2,3);

// works fine
document.writeln(vector.x);

// works in chrome but not in firefox
vector.x = vector.y + vector.z;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem very interesting and has researched it. I am able to reproduce the problem you faced. The setter never gets called but the getter is called. On exploring, found the following text:

```
JavaScript 1.8.1 note
Starting in JavaScript 1.8.1, setters are no longer called when setting properties in object and array initializers.
```

Look at the URL: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Also has more references: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.8.1

And https://dev.mozilla.jp/localmdc/localmdc_11696.html

The reason cited as security vulnerability (affected twitter)
Follow a discussion on this in chromium [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=73636)

Comment: Thanks for the research. What I don't get is, I'm not setting a property in an object or array initializer so should this realy not work?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that Firefox just doesn't allow setting any non-numeric properties on typed arrays; any such sets are ignored.  And they're ignored before searching the prototype chain, which is why your setter on the prototype is not being invoked.

It's not clear to me what the right behavior here is per spec; it's changed a few times in this area.

Note https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=695438